# Does a smart contract browser or explorer exist?

Tags: smart-contracts

Is there any smart contract browser or explorer currently available? (i.e. a web browser-based tool where someone can easily audit the code held in the blockchain)

Comment: I suppose you search something like: 

1) go to https://alphanet.tzscan.io/<smart-contract-address>

2) open "Code" tab.

Now you can read smart-contract code on Michelson, and see smart-contract values of variables (on tab "Storage"). Also you can open and convert Michelson code to liquidity, button "Open in Try-Liquidity"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baking Bad has released a smart contract explorer called "Better Call Dev". It offer a lot of useful functionalities, for example easy exploration of the state of the contract etc...

https://better-call.dev/

https://medium.com/coinmonks/michelson-rocks-but-you-better-call-dev-e23cd32a299a